# how to implement a relative timer in a game

Tags: mmo

Our game is a MMO game, and our logic server has a game loop of course. To make these logical module easy to write, we provide a timer module, which support register a real timer and trigger it when it possible. In the game loop, we pass the system time (in millsecond) to timer module, and the timer manager will check if there're some timers can be triggered. For example, to update a player/monster position, when the player start to move, we update the player position every 200ms.

But when the game loop run too much logic, it will use too much time in a single frame, and the next frame, some timer will slower than the real time. That will cause some bugs actually. For example, if in one frame, it spent 1 second, and in the next frame, the real time is 1000ms, and the move timer has scheduled in 800ms, so the timer has been triggered at 1000ms, slower than the expected time.

So is there any better solutions to solve this problem ? For example, we can implement a timer, only dependent on our game, not dependent on the real computer time ?

Comment: Captain Obvious here: have you tries using threads?